# Celery manually store results in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

Since celery is storing the results by their task_id and creating queues infinitely, I'd like to turn on the RESULT IGNORE, but I do want manually to write to a specific rabbit queue the result by myself.

is that possible? how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`kombu`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kombu/) directly. You already have it if you're running `celery`.